# How to play a background music and make it loop?

Tags: c#, loops, background, playback

How to play a background music and make it loop?

Currently I'm using this piece of code to make it play the background music:

XNA-C#

```
SoundEffect bgEffect;
bgEffect = Content.Load<SoundEffect>("EpicUnease");
bgEffect.Play(0.1f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
```

Comment: Hi, Im not sure if this is XNA or c# or are they the same thing?

Comment: XNA is a framework, C# is a programming language

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If this is not XNA, you can reference `System.Media` and do this:

```
SoundPlayer sound = new SoundPlayer("path");`
sound.PlayLooping();
```

For XNA you would do something like this:

```
SoundEffect bgEffect;
bgEffect = Content.Load<SoundEffect>("EpicUnease");
SoundEffectInstance instance = bgEffect .CreateInstance();
instance.IsLooped = true;
bgEffect.Play(0.1f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
```

For more information, check out this msdn article: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd940203.aspx

Comment: It's highly likely to be with XNA, seeing the Content.Load<SoundEffect>() method call.

Comment: Hi sorry about that, I need to use Content.Load<>, I have the music inside my content folder.

Comment: can anyone help me out please?