# c# SoundPlayer playlist loop

Tags: c#, background-music, soundplayer

Maybe I have a simple question, but I am little bit confused from MSDN. I want to use something to play music. I know it may sound easy.

```
private void playMusic(string path) {
        using (SoundPlayer player = new SoundPlayer(path)) {
            player.PlayLooping();                   
        }
    }
```

This is working fine, but what about more sounds in .PlayLooping? or changing volume? There must be some solution with SoundPlayer, isn't it?

I would like to use in MOGRE program and firstly I tried to use `MogreFreeSL`, but it is useless for me.

I just want background music with more then one sound, it must be very simple.

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8182738/c-sharp-how-to-play-a-background-music-and-make-it-loop

Comment: XNA is very nice thing but I am working in MOGRE and the other way is the way what I am using now...just one song.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe MogreFreeSL doesn't work very well? I've used Mogre in my own projects with IrrKlang and it works just fine with multiple sounds. Maybe you could try that?

IrrKlang: http://www.ambiera.com/irrklang/

Sample code: http://sourceforge.net/p/ponykart/code/832/tree/trunk/Ponykart/Sound/ (though it's a little broken at the moment)